# Prove X is before Y Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have these facts:

```
before CS206 is CS121
before CS121 is CS120
before CS120 is CS101
before CS101 is CS100
```

I am trying to write some Prolog code to prove `before CS206 is CS100`

This is what I have but I am getting a stack overflow because my recursion is messed up

```
before(X,Y) :- before(X,Z), before(Z,Y).
before(X,X).
before(CS101,CS100).
before(CS120,CS101).
before(CS121,CS120).
before(CS206,CS121).
```

Comment: `before(X, X)` is true? `X` comes before `X`?

Comment: Yeah you are right that should not be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, atoms starting with a capital letter are to be single quoted, otherwise they are variables. So `CS101` is a variable and `'CS101'` is and atom.

So your facts should be written as

```
before('CS101', 'CS100').
before('CS120', 'CS101').
before('CS121', 'CS120').
before('CS206', 'CS121').
```

Adding the following rule only

```
before(X, Y) :- before(X, Z), before(Z, Y).
```

you should be able to prove that

```
before('CS206', 'CS100')
```

is true.